# System.Numerics.Vector.GreaterThan and bool results

Tags: c#, simd

I am trying to convert some existing code that can be optimized using SIMD instructions. There is a mask generation code that I am testing how much performance I can get out of SIMD after converting it and the below is a oversimplified chunk I am using to profile it.

```
Random r = new Random();
var random1 = new double[65536000*4];
var random2 = new double[random1.Length];
var result = new bool[random1.Length];
for (i = 0; i < random1.Length; i++)
{
    random1[i] = r.Next();
    random2[i] = r.Next();
}

var longRes = new long[random1.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i += Vector<double>.Count)
{
    Vector<double> v1 = new Vector<double>(random1, i);
    Vector<double> v2 = new Vector<double>(random2, i);
    Vector<long> res = System.Numerics.Vector.GreaterThan(v1, v2);
    res.CopyTo(longRes, i);
}
```

Is there a technique I could use to efficiently put the result `res` into the `result` array?

Originally I thought I could live with `Vector<long>` and keep the masks in `long[]` but I realized that maybe this is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on the original question I came to a realization that `System.Numberics.Vector.GreaterThan` and other similar methods like `LesserThan` etc are designed for use with `ConditionalSelect()`.

In my case, I was attempting to generate a `bool` array that represents an image mask that is later used throughout the API and converting the long to bool wouldn't be feasible.

In other words, these comparison methods were not meant to be for general purpose use.

Comment: IDK if C# stops you from using what the hardware can do, but x86 SIMD can turn a vector compare result into a scalar integer bitmask with one instruction.  The C++ intrinsics is `int _mm_movemask_pd(__m128d)`.  (Also a `_ps` and an `_epi8` version.)  Use bit-shifts / add to combine 4 bitmaps with 2 significant bits each into a byte into a single byte with 8 `double` compare results you can store into a bitmap.

Comment: Or it's totally feasible to pack 4 vectors of 4-byte compare results down to 8-bit integers and store an array of `bool` using 2x `packssdw` => `packsswb` to get byte elements.  You can `AND` them with a vector of `0x1` to convert the 0/-1 vector to 0/1.

Comment: C# may not provide all this as built-in, because ARM NEON / AArch64 AdvSIMD doesn't have an equivalent of x86's `_mm_movemask_pd/ps/epi8`.  But you can still shuffle / pack down to byte elements easily in ARM.  If C# doesn't let you do this somehow, use a better language for your SIMD loops.

Comment: I'll have to digest your comments a bit to make sense of what you're proposing. Likely you disagree with my answer and downvoted it so I'll try to improve it somehow.

Comment: I maybe shouldn't have downvoted, but you claim that they *were not meant to be for general purpose use.*  I'd be surprised and disappointed if C# didn't let you somehow do what you want, because as I said, the hardware has no problem with it.  In asm, [`cmppd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPPD.html) gives you a vector of two `0`/`-1` integer elements, of the same width as the two input `double` operands.  There are shuffle instructions that can pack or truncate that down to 4-byte integers if `long` is 4 bytes.  (I don't know C#).  It's possible that C# SIMD just sucks and makes this hard.

Comment: I upvoted your question, though, because it seems reasonable.  But "it's impossible / infeasible" seems like an unlikely answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's very fair. I could just delete it but I'll try to improve it with the information you added.

Comment: Cool, I'd be happy to upvote if you find out the C# syntax to get asm like `cmppd` / `movmskpd` (bitmap) or 8x `cmppd` / 4x `packssdw` (4-byte elements of 0/-1) / 2x `packssdw` (2-byte elements) / 1x `packsswb` (a single vector of 16 single-byte elements).  When you want to use this array of 0/-1 bytes, you could load it back with SSE4.1 `pmovsxbq` to expand two bytes to two 8-byte elements that line up with a vector of `double`.